# At what point does django write an object to the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I am overriding the save method on one of my Models like so:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        some_stuff()
```

some_stuff() performs some queries which expect that the new/modified Foo object has been saved to the database (which I why I've put it after the super() call). However, I'm finding when some_stuff() runs the newly created/modified object is not present in the DB.

Is my understanding of when things are written to the DB incorrect? How else might I do this (I've considered signals, but all of this is within the same app, so that seems overkill)?

UPDATE: I've tried putting a signal receiver to see if that makes any difference; in fact it gets called before the super() call finishes, so the DB state is no different whether I override save() use a signal.

Comment: are you using TransactionMiddleware?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler - no I'm not; I'm figuring it has to do with the DB not having committed the data, but can't work out why it isn't. I'm using Postgres as my DB.

Comment: Transaction middleware is what would commit stuff for you without you having to call commit yourself.  The easiest solution for you is to add transaction middleware to your middleware setting (in settings.py).  This is exactly what it's for:  to put the DB queries in a request into a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need call some_stuff() like this: self.some_stuff(). `after Super(...)`, the `self` would be the object present in DB. And you can do some with `self` in your method.

Comment: some_stuff() isn't actually a function, I just put it there in the interests of keeping the example brief. In fact, there is some code there which uses another model's objects.

Comment: @askvictor any way ,the `self` will synchronize with DB, after   `Super(..)`. Is this what you want?